# Mobile friendly display of data from mysql

Tags: php, html, css, mobile

I have been looking for help with this for over a week now and no luck, is there anyone who can help me with this? especially considering responsive tables and mobile friendly output of tables.
I have this table 1

[image]

I would like to change table 1 to look like table 2
[mobile friendly version of table to generate][2]

This is the code I have used to generate table 1:
[code for table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6U5l.png)

[image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated, Blessings be.

Comment: please see the code for table 1

Comment: don't post your code as an image

Comment: @e4c5 Is there a specific reason why not to post code as image? Asking just for clarity.

Comment: If someone wanted to try out this query how is he going to copy paste?

Comment: Alright, thanks @e4c5